# PHPMailer SMTP Connection Failed with Gmail o Domain - GoDaddy

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am working on a website with a form that is used to send email with PHPMailer. i have a GoDaddy hosting plan linux.  I have tried multiple ways without any success, some time ago it worked and now does not work.

**Configuration 1 with Gmail**

```
include_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
include_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');



$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false; (I've tried the 2 options)
$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username ='xxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';
$mail->Subject = 'Form from website'; 

$mail->AddAddress("xxxxx@xxxx.com");
$mail->FromName   = "formsite"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
```

Log

> Connection: opening to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:25, timeout=300, options=array ()
>
> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

**Configuration 2 email from the same domain**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPSecure = true; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;  // Enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->Host = 'p3plcpnxxx.prod.phx3.secureserver.net';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username ='noreply@samedomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx'; 
$mail->Subject = 'Form from website';
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxx@xxxx.com");
$mail->FromName   = "formsite";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
```

**Log**

> SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-p3plcpnxxxx.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.89 #1 Thu, 14 Dec 2017 21:11:11 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
>
> CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.xxxxxx.com
>
> SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-p3plcpnxxxx.prod.phx3.secureserver.net Hello 
>   p3plcpnxxxx.prod.phx3.secureserver.net [180.168.200.196]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-CHUNKING250 HELP

Comment: You have not actually asked a question. Your first example looks like a firewall block - ask GoDaddy about that. Your second example is working fine, though `SMTPSecure = true` should be `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'`; Don't just make up values and expect it to work - read the docs and code if you're unsure. You should not need to disable cert verification; GoDaddy shouldn't be publishing bad certs, and you should have up to date CA certificates. You're using an old version of PHPMailer, and you've based your code on an obsolete example, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 1):

To help others struggling with GoDaddy, these two variations worked for me:

Hosting: GoDaddy shared/cPanel

Sending "From:" a GMail address

PHPMailer version 6.0.5

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

  $send_using_config = 1; // set to 1, 2, etc. to test different settings
  switch ($send_using_config):
    case 1:
      $mail->Host = 'localhost';
      $mail->Port = 25;
      $mail->SMTPSecure = FALSE;
      $mail->SMTPAuth = FALSE;
      $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
      break;
    case 2:
      # Host amnd Port info obtained from:
      #   Godaddy > cPanel Home > Email > cPanel Email > Mail Configuration > "Secure SSL/TLS Settings" > Outgoing Server
      $mail->Host = 'a2plcpnxyzw.prod.iad2.secureserver.net';
      $mail->Port = 465;
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
      $mail->SMTPAuth = FALSE;
      $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
          'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => FALSE,
            'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
            'allow_self_signed' => TRUE
          )
      );
      break;
  endswitch;

  $mail->Username = 'you@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'your_gmail_password';

  $mail->setFrom($from);
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->msgHTML($message);
  $mail->send();
```

These settings are based on the question posted here and modified with the advice from @Synchro on StackOverflow and GitHub. Thank you @Synchro!